# Are closures a violation of the functional programming paradigm?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, closures

Functional programming "avoids state and mutable data".

Closures hide state by binding their lexical environment and are thus closed over their free **variables**.

How is Haskell purely-functional if it supports closures? Don't they break referential transparency?

Comment: Since when do variables break referential transparency? Math is as referentially transparent as it gets, yet those pesky mathematicans juggle variables all day.

Comment: The implementation might involve state, but there's not any mutation going on semantically speaking.

Comment: Free variables in Haskell function can be either other functions, constant applicative forms or already applied arguments (partial application), nothing of which breaks referential transparency.

Comment: Many thanks, your comments are very helpful. I suppose the question that follows logically for me is why even call them closures then? In the purely mathematical sense a set is closed under an operation, but the only real operation is reference.

Comment: Closures are so called because they _close over the variables_ i.e. hold them fixed to a given value.

Comment: @solo: Actually, I just checked Haskell 2010 report and the word "closure" is used only to describe some module characteristics.

Comment: I recently ran across [this recommendation](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/words-matter/) of using the word "variable" in the mathematical sense, and "assignable" to denote procedural-style reassignable variables. It would go a long way to clearing up this confusion.

Comment: @DanielLyons that does make it a great deal more clear. Thank you for linking the article.

Comment: Closures are an implementation technique, it may or may not be used when implementing Haskell.

Comment: I imagine it would be quite difficult to implement "functional" programming without *some* runtime representation of a function.

Comment: @Dan Burton - defunctionalization is used by MLton to implement SML without runtime closures. I think Boquist's Haskell compiler used defunctionalization also.

Comment: @DanD. this is redefining the well-established concept, i.e. changing the meaning of the word. IOW, a big fat **NO-NO**. The concept of "closure" was born long before Haskell, and specifically in the context of closing over a *free* ***mutable*** variable, finding ways to represent lexical scoping in a run-time construct.

Comment: @WillNess, so are you saying that you agree that closures are a 'violation' of FP, at least in a language such as JavaScript where the captured context includes mutable variables?

Comment: @JonCoombs I didn't try to answer this question; I just posted a specific response to a specific comment. -- Mutable variables hidden in closures enable object-oriented programming. Pure FP indeed eschews mutation. Absent mutation, talking about closures doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Haskell, closures have free variables in the same way that in math you can write `f x = x^2` - it doesn't mutate state.

I would say that Haskell avoids *mutable* state.

Answer (score 20):

Closures are not a violation because all bindings in Haskell are immutable.  What closures really mean is that a lambda with free variables doesn't denote one unique function; it will denote different functions depending on the bindings that are in effect for its free variables when each time it is evaluated.  E.g.:

```
makeClosure :: Num a => a -> a -> a
makeClosure x = \y -> x+y
```

The expression `makeClosure 5` evaluates to a different function than `makeClosure 6`; and much more importantly, two occurrences of `makeClosure 5` in different parts of the program **evaluate to the same function**, as does `makeClosure (2+3)` or similar; i.e., we have **referential transparency** (substituting expressions with their equals preserves the meaning of a program).

You seem to be confused over the meaning of "state" in the quote you mention.  State in this context means mutable data; closures can definitely "hide" data, but in Haskell this data is not mutable, so it doesn't hide state.  As a contrast to this, in my experience Java programmers often say that a class instance "hides state" in cases where the data in question is not mutable, e.g., assigned to a `private final` instance field from the constructor; what they really mean is that classes (and closures) **encapsulate** data.

Answer (score 15):

No, closures are fine and don't cause problems in Haskell because a closure closes over the *values* of the free variables.  The reason you can hide state behind closures in other languages is that you close over the *reference*.  As you know, in Javascript:

```
var x = 1;
var f = function(y) { return y + x; }
f(2)  // => 3
x = 2;
f(2)  // => 4
```

You can actually model this by using `IORef`s in Haskell:

```
main = do
  x <- newIORef 1
  let f y = do x' <- readIORef x
               return (y + x')
  r1 <- f 2
  writeIORef x 2
  r2 <- f 2
```

This is OK because function `f` has type `Int -> IO Int` rather than `Int -> Int`.  In other words, `f` is bound to the same action, but *when executed* that same action may return different results each time.

Comment: Nice job. I've often seen comments about closures as "a staple of functional programming" mentioned glibly in discussions of JavaScript closures. The irony is that you can get various state-related effects/bugs if you aren't careful with JS closures because they're holding onto a reference rather than to a value. One solution is to explicitly pass the value in as a parameter *instead of* using the closure context (i.e. passing both x and y in as parameters of your function f above). So that's actually the more 'functional' approach, right?

Answer (score 2):

My working man's definition of "functional programming" is that if you put the same thing(s) in, you *always* get the same thing(s) out.

Closures do not violate this definition in Haskell (try and come up with a closure that does :) ), therefore closures don't violate the FP paradigm.